# Insertar HTML dentro de un String en typescript

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

Buen día, quisiera saber como puedo insertar codigo HTML dentro de mi constante en typescript

Codigo

```js
const tcText = 'To continue downloading your files, , you may click on ${<a class="skip 2" (click)="onSetEmail()">Skip</a>}` "to download links directly.';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mientras cumplas las reglas de sintaxis de los strings, puedes embeber todo el HTML que quieras. Por reglas, me refiero a que el string inicie y termine correctamente. En la práctica, si vas a utilizar comillas dobles dentro del HTML, puedes iniciar y terminar el string dentro de tu código ts con comillas simples.

```js
function onClick() {
  alert('The button was clicked');
}

const tcText = 'To continue downloading your files, you may click on <a class="skipBtn" onClick="onClick()">Skip</a> to download links directly.';
document.getElementById('elemnt').innerHTML = tcText;
```

```css
.skipBtn {
  color: white;
  background-color: maroon;
}
```

```html
<div id="elemnt"></div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me fue util!!

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="elemnt"></div>
<script>
    const tcText = 'To continue downloading your files, , you may click on <a class="skip 2" style="color:red" onclick="onSetEmail()">Skip</a>` "to download links directly.'
    document.getElementById("elemnt").innerHTML=tcText;
</script>
```